# Unexpected R behavior with function parameter

Tags: r, function, parameters

Am R newb.  I coded a function that uses 3 parameters.   In my code i use one of the parameters to help me read files from a directory.  There are 100 files in the directory.   The code works fine when I pass it all the function parameters and specify the files i want to read.

```
functionX(var1, var2, id) and functionX(var1, var2, id = 1:100)

## Below is the first line of code for me that uses "id".

sub.file.names  <- file.names[id]   ### Get file names
```

The odd thing is that when a value for "id" is not passed to the function initially (or set with a 1:100 default), the code seems to read all the file names anyway.   And it does so even though a value for "id" has never been established.

It's as if R somehow treats the two functions below the same when the user omits passing a value to "id" when executing the function ... eg, functionx("var1", "var2")  ## and does not pass any id variable

```
functionx(var1, var2, id)
functionx(var1, var2, id = 1:100)
```

Any pointers on why this is happening would be great to know.  I feel the answer is obvious, but have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Maybe `if(missing(id)) do something`.`

Comment: You may need to provide more detail of what you've done - have you defined two versions of `functionX()`? If so, the second is overwriting the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to explain what is happening with a simple example. Consider the following function

```
foo = function(i){
  LETTERS[i]
}
```

When you try `foo()`, you will notice that the function returns all 26 uppercase letters. Why does that happen? Well, everything in R is a function. So when you say `LETTERS[i]`, you are essentially calling the function `[`. So, the function call is

```
`[`(LETTERS, i)
```

Since `i` is missing, this call is executed as `[`(LETTERS) (essentially `LETTERS[]`) which returns all elements of the vector. Note that this occurs because the `[` function allows for the `i` argument to be missing while calling it. Check `?`[

If you want the function to act differently when `id` is missing, either check for `missing(id)`, or explicitly set it to NULL as default. So, if you do

```
foo2 = function(i = NULL){
  LETTERS[i]
}
```

`foo2()` will return a zero length character vector.

Comment: dang, beat me to it :-)

Comment: Thx Ramnath - great explanation and solid examples.   I also appreciate that you added the part about about explicitly setting with NULL if I wanted different behavior.